# Updating current Symfony User is attempting CREATE

Tags: symfony, security, doctrine, token, saml

Ive set up Symfony 4 to use a SAML login system. When a user is authenticated using SAML the UserFactory gets the User from the database if they already exist or persists and flushes a new user entity.

In a controller, Im then trying to use some simple code:

```
$user = $this->getUser(); // Returns an App\User\Entity object
$user->setFirstName('Test');
$this->em->persist($user);
$this->em->flush(); // Errors here
```

But Doctrine treats this user as a new entity, or throws an error that some parameters are missing.

I could just get the User again from the database, but that would mean doing it every time I wanted to use the current User object to do something.

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($this->getUser()->getId())
```

The issue seems to be possibly related to the serialize and unserialize methods within the user class, as these attributes are the only ones available in the user object.

```
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->firstName,
        $this->lastName,
        $this->email,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->username,
    ));
}

public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->firstName,
        $this->lastName,
        $this->email,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->username,
        ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]
    );
}
```

Once the user is authenticated, theyre stored in the session. The $this->getUser() is what is being returned form the Security Token, so Im confused as to why this would be different from a standard login authentication.

How can I ensure the full User object is available through $this->getUser()?

Comment: Try Doctrine as follows. $this->getDoctrine()->getManager() I tried this way and did not encounter any problems.  What kind of error do you get

Comment: Im trying to avoid pulling the User from Doctrine on every request, it should exist already in the security token. Im guessing I need to change something in a UserFactory or UserProvider somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Even though your unserialized user has identifier it is unknown to Doctrine thus the insertion. To let Doctrine know about your entity you can use [merge](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities) (please note it returns a *new* instance of the entity).